# Force Masonry/similar to ignore flow and fill gaps instead

Tags: javascript, css, layout, jquery-masonry

Masonry/Isotope/Freetile and the rest do a great job at absolute positioning elements in a grid/container.

However, when an element takes the full width of the grid/container, it creates massive gaps which is not an acceptable outcome.

Here is a jsfiddle to my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/QNf3A/1/

There's enough room on the top of the red div to place a green one. However, the different libraries tend to respect the flow as opposed to a "leave no gaps" philosophy.

Does anyone know of an alternative js library or similar trick to avoid gaps?

-

Code from jsfiddle...

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="block half"></div>
    <div class="block full"></div>
    <div class="block half"></div>
    <div class="block half"></div>
    <div class="block half"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
    width: 600px;
    background-color: #EEE;
}
.block{
  float: left;
}
.half{
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #CFC;
}
.full{
    width: 600px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #FCC;
}
```

JS/jQuery:

```
$(function($) {

  $('#container').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.block',
    columnWidth: 300
  });

});
```

Comment: I wonder how the questioner solved this one? :\

Comment: Just posted this script from the author of Packery (also a good option): https://github.com/DrewDahlman/Mason

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this:
https://github.com/DrewDahlman/Mason

And seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if this answer is too late or not but check out Packery. It's a masonry type plugin that does just this:

https://github.com/metafizzy/packery

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, the author created this new library: https://github.com/DrewDahlman/Mason

Comment: packery is the way to go imho. Mason.JS (github.com/DrewDahlman/Mason) doesn't seem to be as flexible.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is 2-dimensional packing.  Perfect masonry http://www.drewdahlman.com/meusLabs/?p=218 can solve some problems related to gaps.